# Must an adverbial subordinate clause attach to an independent clause?

Tags: subordinate-clauses, participle-phrases

> Having received mixed or outright negative reactions **when they were released**, these movies were only appreciated in their later years.

Is there a rule that says adverbial subordinate clauses must connect to an independent clause (see the example below)? Can they modify the verb in a phrase? Traditional grammar resources fail to provide examples such as the one above (a perfect participle phrase).

> The films received mixed or outright negative reactions **when they were released**.

Comment: People have later years. Not movies. For movies: years later. Also, I don't see any "attachment".

Comment: I think the point still holds (choice of words notwithstanding). By attachment, I mean that they are used in parallel. For example, 'The films received mixed or outright negative reactions when they were released.' There is undoubtedly a better way to phrase it, but I don't see the need to nitpick. If you were legitimately confused, I hope this has helped.

Comment: Adverbial subordinate clauses such as the highlighted "fronted" text in your example don't really impose any restrictions on the tense of main clause they modify. So ***Having passed your driving test...*** could be followed by any of ***...you were able to drive your own car last year, ...you can drive your own car now, ...you will be able to drive your own car next year***.

Comment: (also various more "exotic" verb forms in main clauses could occur in my example: ***... you would have been able to insure your own car, you are sitting pretty as regards insurance premiums,...***)

Comment: I think the focus of my question is being lost a bit here. The nature of time isn't what confuses me; it's the inclusion of an adverbial subordinate clause as part of a phrase. In this example, 'when they were released' modifies 'received'. The independent clause that the entire phrase modifies is entirely redundant—included to complete the example sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking whether "when they were released", the adverbial clause, can attach to the gerund-participial clause "having received ... reactions", which is a subordinate clause, an adjunct modifying *movies*, the subject of the main clause.
Yes, it can, and your example is grammatical.

I agree with the comment that "in their later years" doesn't fit semantically with a movie, because movies don't have fixed lifetimes.

Comment: May I ask why you classify the adjunct as a subordinate clause? In various resources (and according to my own understanding), this would be classified as a phrase. It has no subject — although you seem to be implying that 'having' is a gerund — so I'm not sure how this fits the requirements of a clause. (I am not saying you're wrong, for clarity. I am just confused.)

Comment: It has an implied subject. It would be clearer if the word order were changed: These movies, having received ... reviews, were only appreciated later.

Comment: Interesting. This resource (https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-participial-phrase-1691588) implies that the terms are used interchangeably, but 'phrase' appears more common. Either way, it is useful to know.

Comment: This reference: https://tinyurl.com/3mnwkjrw refers to "gerund-participial clauses", and an example is parallel to yours: "having read the paper, I can't see why you care."

Comment: I should have referred to "when they were released" as an adverbial clause, not a phrase, in my answer, which I will correct.